# What is "quiet splash" in the grub file for?

Tags: grub2, shutdown

I've been here for a while, and sometimes I see people answering questions related to shutdown or restart problems with this : "delete `"quiet splash"` from the `/etc/default/grub` file".
My question is: what is `"quiet splash"` for?

Comment: I like messages (even if some are errors, eg. no hibernate file found is an error meaning only that the machine boots normally instead of loading hibernate file; this error means nothing but can still *scare*  users) but `quiet` hides these messages *keeping users happy*.    `splash` just gives a pretty (moving) picture for users to not-think-its-stalled *making them even happier*   A choice of lots of info, or being *happy in [igno..] bliss*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `quiet` prevents Linux from giving shell output of your boot process, and the `splash` option show the boot screen. If you remove both you will get an output if you updated your grub afterwards with:

```
sudo update-grub
```